What is the origin of kosa-kusi?
I have seen in the eastern side of India, that often kosa-kusi is used in puja for achaman and samanya arghya sthapan. I would to know what is the origin of this kosa-kusi, is there any scripture that mentions it?
This kosa-kusi is generally made of copper however on rare occasions I have seen kosa-kusi of silver in some temples and mathas.
My question is what are the metals through which kosa-kusi can be made amongst Gold, Silver, Copper and Kansa?

Only used in Bengal and probably in Assam too .. in other regions of India a Pancha Patra is used instead.

@Rickross what is significance of it?  Does it have Shakta origin ? Panch patra is simple water container.

I doubt if it is related to Shaktism because even Vaishnavas in Bengal use them @SpiritualAspirant
